# Как программно нажать кнопку?

Tags: c#

Как программно нажать кнопку?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

button.PerformClick() ?

Answer (score 7):

Если нужно нажать кнопку в **чужом** приложении, то есть варианты:

- эмулировать нажатия обычных и горячих с помощью вызовов SendKeys;
- использовать P/Invoke для нахождения хэндлов кнопок и посылки сообщений SendMessage;
- использовать UI Automation API ([пример](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-6-automated-ui-testing/)).

Answer (score 5):

**`button1.PerformClick();`**

---

Только смотри ни в коем случае не делай так в самом событии нажатия на кнопку, иначе будет бесконечная рекурсия вызовов кликов!

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Мир.");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

если окно приложения будет скрыто или свернуто, то кнопка нажиматься не будет:

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

так в любом случае будет вызываться событие нажатия кнопки:

```
button1_Click(null, null);
```