# Как программно поставить фокус на ToolStripButton, если их несколько?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как программно поставить фокус на ToolStripButton внутри ToolStrip, если их несколько?

Comment: Найти нужный, например по значению свойства `Name`, и поставить фокус. А в чем трудность? Это такой же контрол, как и все остальные.

Comment: Как раз таки он не контрол.

Comment: Действительно, что-то я подзабыл... Печально. Но все равно все просто, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Инициализация
ToolStrip tStrip1 = new ToolStrip();
ToolStripButton toolStripButton1 = new ToolStripButton(){Name = "tsButton1"};
ToolStripButton toolStripButton2 = new ToolStripButton(){Name = "tsButton2"};
tStrip1.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] {toolStripButton1, toolStripButton2});
//Фокус
public void SetFocused(ToolStrip element, string name)
{
    element.Focus();
    foreach (var item in element.Items)
    {
        if (item is ToolStripButton)
        {
            if (((ToolStripButton)item).Name.Equals(name))
            {
                ((ToolStripButton)item).Select();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем это нужно `item.Select();`?

Comment: @tym32167 это аналог Focus() для ToolStripButton.

Comment: Фокус поставлен. А как на нее программно нажать?

Comment: @Antinet ???https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/129575/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83?rq=1 Смотрите похожие вопросы справа

Comment: @Antinet ToolStripButton поддерживает метод PerformClick()

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        var ts = new ToolStrip
        {
            Name = "ts"
        };
        Controls.Add(ts);
        ts.Items.Add(new ToolStripButton("Кнопка 1", null, null, "tsb1"));
        ts.Items.Add(new ToolStripButton("Кнопка 2", null, null, "tsb2"));
        ts.Items.Add(new ToolStripButton("Кнопка 3", null, null, "tsb3"));

        Load += Form1_Load;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ts = Controls["ts"] as ToolStrip;
        ts.Focus();
        ts.Items["tsb3"].Select();
    }
}
```

В данном примере будет фокус будет сразу передан на "Кнопка 3". Как видите, перебирать коллекцию элементов не обязательно, у коллекций присутствует индексатор по свойству Name

Comment: Фокус поставлен. А как на нее программно нажать?

Comment: @Antinet Стоп, а зачем вам программно нажимать, у вас же сеть доступ к коду, который она выполняет. Вынесите код обработчика события в отдельную функцию и вызывайте везде, где надо, в том числе в обработчике.

Comment: @Antinet Ну и ToolStripItem тоже умеет в [PerformCkick](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.performclick?view=netframework-4.8)